# CDK: Possible to put the stack created for EdgeFunction resource in another (cross-region) stack?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-lambda-edge

## Problem statement

I have my main CDK stack in `eu-west-1`, but an `EdgeFunction` is created in `us-east-1`.

I have noticed two weird things with `EdgeFunction`:

1. Even if declared in a `NestedStack` they appear in `cdk ls` as `edge-lambda-stack-nnnnnnnnn` (unless given an explicit name).
2. When removing the main stack, let's call it `primary`, it does *not* remove the lambda stack. Probably because (1) above tells me it's not a part of the `NestedStack`.

I have tried putting the `EdgeFunction` in a separate stack created in `us-east-1` explicitly and then cross-referencing it from `primary` but that fails with "Cannot use resource in a cross-environment fashion" (amongst others).

## Questions

- Why doesn't `cloudfront.experimental.EdgeFunction` respect the `NestedStack` boundary?
- Can I somehow build a `Stack` that exists in `us-east-1` and cross-reference the lambda into my main stack in `eu-west-1`?
- Can I at least make it so that deleting the `primary` stack also automatically deletes the lambda stack.

The reason I'm asking is because I have a number of environments and a number of lambdas and the combinatorial explosion of stacks makes things a bit unwieldly.

## Example

CDK version 1.116

```js
import "source-map-support/register";
import * as cdk from "@aws-cdk/core";
import * as cloudfront from "@aws-cdk/aws-cloudfront";
import * as lambda from "@aws-cdk/aws-lambda";
import * as path from "path";

class PrimaryStack extends cdk.Stack {
    constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
        super(scope, id, props);
        new SecondaryStack(this, "secondary-stack");
    }
}

class SecondaryStack extends cdk.NestedStack {
    constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string) {
        super(scope, id);

        new cloudfront.experimental.EdgeFunction(this, "my-lambda", {
            runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_14_X,
            functionName: "my-lambda",
            handler: "index.handler",
            code: lambda.Code.fromAsset(
                path.join(__dirname, "..", "lib", "my-lambda"),
            ),
        });
    }
}


const app = new cdk.App();

new PrimaryStack(app, "primary", {
    env: { account: "123", region: "eu-west-1" },
});
```

`cdk ls` output:

```sh
edge-lambda-stack-cnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
primary
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I talked to AWS premium support and the answer is that it doesn't seem like CDK can handle this by using nested stacks.

Instead, create a separate stack for the EdgeLambdas in `us-east-1` and then export the ARNs of the lambdas to SSM.

In the other stack, [import the ARNs from SSM and use those](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/1575#issuecomment-674767075).

This will result in the minimum amount of stacks to handle. You will still need to deploy the two stacks separately.

The code I ended up using looks like this:

```js
export function exportLambdaSsm(
    func: cloudfront.experimental.EdgeFunction,
): ssm.StringParameter {
    const funcName = // ...
    return new ssm.StringParameter(this, `${funcName}-param`, {
        // Parameter with slash must start with a slash
        parameterName: `/${funcName}`,
        stringValue: func.functionArn,
    });
}

export function importLambdaFromSsm(stack: Stack): lambda.IVersion {
    const funcName = // ...
    const funcResource = new cr.AwsCustomResource(stack, `${funcName}-param`, {
        policy: cr.AwsCustomResourcePolicy.fromStatements([
            new iam.PolicyStatement({
                effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
                actions: ["ssm:GetParameter*"],
                resources: [
                    stack.formatArn({
                        service: "ssm",
                        region: "us-east-1",
                        resource: "parameter",
                        resourceName: funcName,
                    }),
                ],
            }),
        ]),
        onUpdate: {
            // will also be called for a CREATE event
            service: "SSM",
            action: "getParameter",
            parameters: {
                Name: `/${funcName}`,
            },
            region: "us-east-1",
            // Update physical id to always fetch the latest version
            physicalResourceId: cr.PhysicalResourceId.of(Date.now().toString()),
        },
    });

    return lambda.Version.fromVersionArn(stack, funcName, funcResource.getResponseField("Parameter.Value"));
}
```

Please be aware that when fetching and storing SSM values there are a lot of rules around where slashes go. I tried to keep the code above correct.